# Why can't I change the environment of an S4 method?

Tags: r, r-s4

It is quite simple to change the environment of a standard R function:

```
foo <- function(x) x + z
env0 <- new.env()
env0$z <- 0
environment(foo) <- env0
z <- 1
foo(3)
```

However, the same type of assignment cannot be performed on an S4 method:

```
setClass(Class = "MyClass", 
  representation = representation(
    x = "numeric"
  )
)

myClass <- function(n) {
  new("MyClass",
    x = rnorm(n)
  )
}

setGeneric(
  name = "foo",
  def = function(object) {standardGeneric("foo")}
)
setMethod(
  f = "foo", 
  signature = "MyClass",
  definition = function(object) {
    sqrt(abs(xx))
  }
)

# Here everything is Ok
showMethods("foo")

e1 <- new.env()
e1$xx <- st@x
environment(foo) <- e1

# After the environment assignment foo is no longer a method of class MyClass
showMethods("foo")
```

Is there a way to assign a new environment to the method foo?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?